# Check if $.ajax has already been sent and if so then retrieve data without resending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax request that is sent from javascript in my page

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/get.php",
   data:{id:ids},
   type: 'GET',
   async: false,
   success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
   }
});
```

This returns an array of items with some text and ...

Now if the user clicks on a certain button the data needs to be copied to another place on the page(div)

Is there any way I can get the data again from the file (in the network tab "chrome") without resending the request?

Comment: Store `data` in a variable and retrieve it from there later when you need it.

Comment: add `cache: true` to the list of parameters.

Comment: is this the only way? because what if the page is full with data, would be using an array a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the response in `global variable` (dataArray) and every time check that variable has value or not. So that request will not send further time. Also, you can use that global variable (dataArray) in other methods.

```
var dataArray = "";
function getData(){
 if(dataArray != ""){
   $.ajax({
    url: "/get.php",
    data:{id:ids},
    type: 'GET',
    //async: false,
    success: function(data) {
       //alert(data);
       dataArray = data;
    }
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: `async: false,` why??

Comment: Commented!! actually that is not needed here.. I just copied from the questioner..thanks

Comment: OP has `async: false`.  It's probably not needed.